# printf: Mixing va_list and varargs

Tags: c, printf, variadic-functions

I have a logging function which is implemented along the following lines.  The basic idea is that I want to give the user printf-like formatting, but to prefix the logged string with a timestamp and add a '\n' at the end:

```
void write_log(bb_log_level_t level, const char *fmt, ...) {
    if (level >= current_log_level) {
        // prefix with timestamp and log level name
        printf("%20s [%s]: ", get_timestamp(), log_level_name(level));
        // print user's message
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, fmt);
        vprintf(fmt, ap);
        va_end(ap);
        // end with newline
        printf("\n");
}
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to roll this all into a single `vprintf` call.

I'm guessing the answer is 'no' because there's no published interface for modifying the va_list, and extending the fmt string would take more work than simply calling printf / vprintf / printf.  But it couldn't hurt to ask...

Comment: Even if you could reduce it to one vprintf() call, it's not clear that you'd gain anything by doing so, other than a shorter `write_log()` implementation.

Comment: Your main alternative involves formatting the prefix information and the main printing into a buffer string which is then written once. Another possibility is to could create a modified format that contains the prefix information (with any `%` symbols in it neutralized) and then call `vprintf()` with the modified format and the variable arguments.  If you keep multiple calls to `printf()` etc, you may want to use `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()` to prevent interleaving of concurrent calls from multiple threads.  You can analyze the format string to decide if there's a newline at the end, too.

Comment: If it's not broken, don't fix it

Comment: As Jonathan lays out, it looks like _more_ code just to get a single call of `vprintf()`.

Comment: I do exactly this in my own custom logging functions.  It's simple and it works.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not extend the provided `va_list` inside this function (after the call was already made), in standard C. You could create a macro that extends `va_list` and the format string, before you call the function (see below).

The reason is, that the `va_list` is placed on stack (at least in most implementations), some (most/all?) implementations place additional data after that (return address, local variables, ...). You want to extend that list, but you may don't have space after it, because it is used, so there is no way to extend it without complicated assembler hacking.

Well, you can do the serialisation of the data not in `(v)printf()` but do it yourself, but why should you do that? You could also use `vsnprintf()`, but that would be useless as well. It would reduce the call to `(v)printf() to 1 call, but you don't gain anything from it.

Like this:

```
char buffer[1024];
if( vsnprintf(buffer,1024,fmt,ap)<0 )
  { va_end(ap); return -1; }
printf("%20s [%s]: %s\n", get_timestamp(), log_level_name(level), buffer);
```

Note: Not sure if `'\0'` is included in `buffer` when the output would be longer than `1024`. You would have to check that. You also have to worry about the maximum output length, is `1024` enough?

---

#### Edit:

Made an example using a macro before the call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

//Unrelated stuff, just so that it compiles with the function used in the example
unsigned current_log_level=5;

const char *get_timestamp(void) 
{ return "2023-05-05"; }

const char *log_level_name(unsigned level) 
{ (void)level; return "LevelTest"; }


//modified write_log() function, assuming fmt has already the correct formating inlcuding header
// and ... contains the argumetns for the header
void write_log(unsigned level, const char *fmt, ...) 
{
  if (level >= current_log_level) 
  {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
  }
}

//New macro, to extend the format and variable arguments
#define CALL_WRITE_LOG(level,fmt,...) \
  write_log(level, "%20s [%s]: " fmt "\n" , get_timestamp(), log_level_name(level), __VA_ARGS__ )

//Test the macro
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  CALL_WRITE_LOG(12," %s %i %p", argv[0], argc, (void*)argv[1] );
  return 0;
}
```